# How to get the algorithm2e package?

Tags: packages, installing, miktex

I am trying to compile a document I built on
another computer using `algorithm2e`. I keep getting
errors when I try to build it with TeXworks. I suspect
I get those errors because it cannot find the
`algorithm2e` package. However I don't know how to get
this package on my MiKTeX.

Comment: Why do you “suspect” this is the reason for the errors? What do the errors say?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Miktex, like any good latex distribution, comes with a package manager. Go to 
start->programs->miktex and check for the "browse packages" entry. I think it is in the "Maintanance" sub-menu. In the manager, just search for the package and install it if necessarry.

Prior to that, you can also check your log file. If the package is not installed you get an error "package xyz.sty not found"

Answer (score 3):

MiKTeX can install missing packages on the fly by default. If it doesn't work, and if you are using latest MiKTeX distribution (MiKTeX 2.9), just run MiKTeX's Package Manager (in start menu) to install `algorightm2e` package.

For installing LaTeX packages manually, see
[How can I manually install a package on MiKTeX (Windows)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2063/how-can-i-manually-install-a-package-on-miktex-windows)