# How to write pseudo algorithm in LaTex (texmaker)?

Tags: packages

I am a new user of LaTeX. I am writing a document in Texmaker. I want to write algorithms with `algorithm`.
The problem is that gives me the error:

```
! LaTeX Error: File `algorithm.sty' not found.
! LaTeX Error: File `algorithmic.sty' not found.
```

A minimal example:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
%\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\begin{document}
\section{Algorithm in \LaTex}
\begin{algorithm}
\begin{algorithmic}
\STATE sort the input set $s_i$
\STATE search for $x_i$ in $s_i$
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

Should I  download algorithm package? If yes then how can I?
I am using Texmaker on Windows XP. I googled it but did not find solutions regarding this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you work on windows, you have a *package manager* like MiKTeX. TeXmaker is only an editor of your `.tex` files. Another software is called by TeXmaker to compile your files and obtain `.pdf` files.

You have to follow this instructions [How to get the algorithm2e package?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9944/how-to-get-the-algorithm2e-package) to update your package manager with algorithm2e or algorithmic package.

Comment: And if I work on Linux ?

Comment: For Linux, the answer is given here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/28632/97981